# google apps script returned objects from contacts

Tags: json, object, google-apps-script, contacts

My Code:

```
function testjson() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('MyFriends');
  var contacts = group.getContacts();
  var json = JSON.stringify(contacts[0]);
  Logger.log(json);
}
```

When using the debugger, I can see that the returned contacts variable is an array of 18 objects. The debugger apparently cannot "expand" the objects. So I included the `JSON.stringify` to get a string. The value of the json variable is `"{}"` after running the code. What I really want is to see the key names in the contacts object so that I can have direct access to the field value. Instead of using `"var name = contacts[i].getFullName();"`, I want to use `"var name = contacts[i].fullname"` or whatever the key is for the fullname.

Answer (score 3):

Google won't let you access the properties of a Contact object like that, you have to use the methods like getFullName() that it provides.

For built-in objects like Array you can list their properties with:

```
function getArrayProperties() {
  Logger.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array));
}
```

But if you try that with the Contact or ContactsApp object:

```
function getContactProperties() {
  var contact = ContactsApp.getContacts()[0]      
  Logger.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(contact));
}
```

you just get: "TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object."

Comment: I'm facing the same situation in Demandware, could you please indicate if there is a mean of accessing those properties at least for reading ?

Comment: Sorry, don't see the relationship between accessing Google Contacts and Demandware :?

Comment: The only relationship is the problem of stringifying objects leading to an useless '{}'. It seems there are "dynamic properties" that cannot be accessed by listing object keys, so I hoped there was some kind of similarity between our problems.